# Windows Services for UNIX 3.5 windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, services

I've searched around Microsoft's site, I've been able to find everything except a x64 version for windows 7.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 Professional

Is there any other version of "Windows Services for UNIX 3.x" I could use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Services for UNIX 3.5 is an old version for previous versions of Windows.

Windows 7 comes with the current version of the Subsystem for UNIX-based applications. You can install it as a Windows component like you would install IIS. (As in click start..control..programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off...)  It is no longer a stand-alone product, it is now a part of Windows.

Unfortunately it doesn't work on Windows 7 Professional, you need Enterprise or Ultimate.

Comment: "Ultimate or better"? What's better than *ultimate*?

Comment: @Daniel: Not Windows? (kidding)

Comment: @grawity You won't find me disagreeing.

Comment: what directory does it install to?

Comment: c:\windows\system32, I think. It's really two files, one is psxss.exe, if I remember correctly.